# "function.js does not exist" when deploying a cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a 2nd generation cloud function as a zip file. The code is the following:

```
// index.js
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
    
functions.http('mp4Transcoder', (req, res) => {});
```

```
// dev-server.js
#!/usr/bin/env node

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const router = express.Router()
const func = require('./index')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/octet-stream' }))
router.post('/transcoder', func.transcode)
router.options('/transcoder', func.transcode)
app.use('/', router)
    
// start the server
const port = 3030
const http = require('http')
app.set('port', port)
const server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(port)
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "transcoder-cloud-function",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

If I copy and paste this code and deploy the cloud function, it works. However, if I zip the three files and try to create uploading the zip file, the deployment fails with "function.js does not exist".

Any ideas of what I could try?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer was simpler than I expected: the zip file had the wrong file structure. Google Cloud is expecting the folder structure zip > your files, not zip > folder > your files, as was the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to deploy an Express app to Cloud Function then you should be passing the Express app instance to the Cloud Function and not use the function as a router. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
// index.js

const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');
const { app } = require('./dev-server.js');

functions.http('mp4transcoder', app);
```

```
// dev-server.js

const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/octet-stream' }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!')
})
// app.use('/', router)

exports.app = app
```

```
// package.json
{
    "name": "transcoder-cloud-function",
    "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.20.1"
    }
}
```

Then try redeploying the function either by uploading the ZIP file or directly using `gcloud` CLI:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy mp4transcoder --gen2 --trigger-http --runtime=nodejs16
```

Also checkout [Cloud Function for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions) as its a bit easier to deploy that way.

Comment: Using your refactored code I get `Invalid 'main' field in in package.json of 'dev-server.js'`

Comment: @rwehresmann can you please update your questions and add relevant screenshots. I can;t see how you are deploying it or where the error shows up.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to change something and the error I mentioned above is not happening anymore. However, the original error of "function.js doesn't exist" is still happening. I added a screenshot with the logs (unfortunately this is all information I receive) @Dharmaraj

Comment: @rwehresmann are you trying to deploy with the minimal code as in my answer or the complete express app you have? Can you try deleting existing function and try to deploy a new one from beginning? Also do note `mp4transcoder` is all lower case and entry point should be `mp4transcoder` instead of default `helloHttp`

Comment: thank you for helping (: I posted an answer about how I fixed it. It was a simple mistake.